# How can I convert MS SQL T-SQL into Subsequent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot, aggregate-functions

Here I have a MS SQL query which I would like to convert into MySQL. I don't know how to deal with that.

```
WITH PartitionData as (
  SELECT
    TOP 10 PurchaseDate.PurchaseDate AS date,
    BatchCode,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY PurchaseDate.PurchaseDate ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS RowNumber

  FROM  tblNutBatches
  INNER JOIN PurchaseDate ON PurchaseDate.PurchaseDate BETWEEN tblNutBatches.Introduction_date AND tblNutBatches.expiration_date 
  WHERE  PurchaseDate.PurchaseDate = '2004-05-01'
   
)

SELECT
  date as date,
  [1],
  [2],
  [3],
  [4],
  [5],
  [6],
  [7],
  [8],
  [9]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      BatchCode,
      RowNumber
    FROM
      PartitionData
  )AS  DataAfterFilter 
  
  PIVOT 
  (

    MAX(BatchCode) FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9])
  ) A
```

***`OUTPUT IN SQL SERVER`***

[image]

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL wants back-ticks instead of square brackets. And LIMIT instead of TOP.

Comment: WHich MySQL verison?

Comment: Thanks for your reply the version is `8.0.22.0`

Comment: You mean `'1'` instead of `[1]`? rest of the code should work accordingly?

Comment: MySQL have no something similar to PIVOT. You need in grouping and conditional aggregation. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and desired result. PS. TSQL code may be removed freely. We don't need it.

Comment: @Akina I am very new at `MySQL` would you kindly guide me with my code which part  need to change what subsequent modification idea as example.

Comment: *would you kindly guide me with my code which part need to change what subsequent modification idea as example.* You may find a lot of examples in searching result by  `conditional aggregation pivot [mysql]` search string.

Comment: What are the problems in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn =  1 THEN BatchCode end) as BatchCode1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn =  2 THEN BatchCode end) as BatchCode2,
    ...
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN BatchCode end) as BatchCode10
FROM (
    SELECT 
        pd.PurchaseDate AS date,
        BatchCode,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pd.PurchaseDate ORDER BY BatchCode) AS rn
    FROM  tblNutBatches nb
    INNER JOIN PurchaseDate pd ON pd.PurchaseDate BETWEEN nb.Introduction_date AND nb.expiration_date 
    WHERE  pd.PurchaseDate = '2004-05-01'
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY date
```

Notes:

- if you want a consistent results, you need `ORDER BY` clauses in the subquery and in `ROW_NUMBER()` - I used `BatchCode`
- do prefix `BatchCode` with the alias of the table it belongs to
- the `PARTITION BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()` and the outer `GROUP BY` clause are not necessary strictly speaking, since the subquery is filtering on just one data anyway; I retained them, in case you need to remove the filtering at some point. Accordingly, I moved the top 10 filtering logic form the subquery to the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GMB but but batch codes are dynamic in that case how would I handle that? I am trying to use your converted code. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: yes, that's not a problem. As in your original, this handles up to 10 batch codes per date.

Comment: Here my `MYSQL` journey begins, how is it instead of MS SQL?